# Hiding the Inbox from the documents directory for File Sharing

Tags: ios, file-sharing, documents, inbox

Is it possible to hide the Inbox from the list displayed of the directories?

For example, in this screenshot from a tutorial, the inbox folder features.  In my app I would prefer it not to.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnE5q.jpg]

Other apps (eg. Molecules) seem to manage this, so I assume it is possible.

(In case anyone is wondering I am a novice developer)

I very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that although the Inbox directory is not writeable, it is deletable.  Files opened through other apps will be automatically placed in this file, and if the inbox does not exist then it is created.  So to get rid of it, simply delete it every time you handle an external file opening.

Very simple, just got thrown when I tried to edit a file in the inbox, which raised an exception, making me think the inbox was write-protected.